# Interpreting image-coordinates submitted for an animated image element in a form

Tags: php, css

I'd like to capture the X:Y values indicating where a user clicked on an animated image by checking the php $_POST array. The problem is that while I can get the input submission info on the static images, I cannot seem to get any values from the animated one.

Here is the complete HTML page and form demonstrating this behavior:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Gunfighter Testing Page</title>
<style>
div {
   width:24px;
   height:24px;
   position:relative;
   -webkit-animation:glide 1s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glide  {
   from {
      left:-400px;
      top:0px;
   }
   
   to {
      left:400px;
      top:0px;
   }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post">
<input type="image" name="Staredown" value="Staredown" alt="Staredown" src="https://i.imgur.com/sQwX4Qg.png">
<input type="image" name="Gesture"  value="Gesture"  alt="Gesture" src="https://i.imgur.com/0iJnH5Q.png"><br>
<div><input type="image" name="Shoot"  value="Shoot"  alt="Shoot" src="https://i.imgur.com/i9oV2j3.png"></div>
</form>
</center>
</body>
```

And here is some php checking for form (button) submission and displaying the coordinates within the image that was clicked on:

```
<?php
//var_dump($_POST);
echo "Form (button click) results (a pefect score is x=32 and y=32: <br>\n";
echo "<p>\n";
if ((isset($_POST["Staredown_x"])) || (isset($_POST["Gesture_x"])) || (isset($_POST["Shoot_x_x"]))){
    switch (true){
        case (isset($_POST["Staredown_x"])):
            echo "Staredown click coords=> X:" . $_POST["Staredown_x"] . "; Y:" . $_POST["Staredown_y"] . ".<br>\n";
            break;
        case (isset($_POST["Gesture_x"])):
            echo "Gesture click coords=> X:" . $_POST["Gesture_x"] . "; Y:" . $_POST["Gesture_y"] . ".<br>\n";
            break;
        case (isset($_POST["Shoot_x"])):
            echo "Shoot click coords=> X:" . $_POST["Shoot_x"] . "; Y:" . $_POST["Shoot_y"] . ".<br>\n";
            break;
    }
} else {
echo "Score will be displayed upon clicking on a button.<br>\n";
}
?>
```

Why can I fetch the click coordinates in the image clicked on if they're static, but cannot get the animated one to behave the same way? The animated image will not populate $_POST["Shoot_x"] with the coordinates of the click (or register in any other way I can seem to collect in php).

Comment: I can’t see where you get button_x or how yousubmit the form even in the first example. Is there a lump of JavaScript we should be looking at?

Comment: No, when using HTML:
<input type="image" name="button1" value="button1" alt="button1" src="button1.png">
... within standard form tags, clicking on the image will POST the form as if the image were a submit button, and report where in the image was clicked. php can fetch the $_POST array populated with the values $_POST["button1_x"] and $_POST["button1_y"] (as in my example -- try it, it works!). Those values will be the x and y coordinates within the image that were clicked on.

That works as described. The only problem I'm having is having that button behave that way once it's animated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have run some code and it seems to work fine. Of course the x and y coordinates are relative to the image but they do get passed and shown (I used var_dump). Could you make your code into a complete php which we could run?

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to help. I have edited the original post to FULLY reflect all the code and demonstrate exactly the behavior that I'm having the problem with. (Running this code may require a server installation that support webkit (I'm afraid I don't know much about that; I'm using hostgator to run this and it just works). A working web page can be seen at: https://gunfighter.io/test/index.php

Comment: Solved! (Embarrassingly). Thanks @AHaworth for attempting to help. A var-dump showed that the moving image was indeed submitting the image map coordinates to the server. I had a typo in my php code checking for the $_POST variable(s) that got populated when clicking on that particular image. Zheesh.

Answer (score 0):

This example works as written IF (unlike me) you pay attention to your typing and check the $_POST["*imagename_x*"] instead of checking $_POST["*imagename_x_x*"] like I was doing.